# Creating Excel XLS files on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xml, xls

I am trying to create a report in Excel format, ready to be sent by email. So far I have found that the best and simplest way is to create an xml document as follows and save it as xls.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"> 
    <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1"> 
        <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="2" ss:ExpandedRowCount="2" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1"> 
            <Row> 
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Name</Data></Cell>
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Example</Data></Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Value</Data></Cell>
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">123</Data></Cell>
            </Row> 
        </Table>
    </Worksheet> 
</Workbook>
```

Then I could save this document using

```
NSArray *documentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *docDir = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Report.xls", [documentDirectoryPath objectAtIndex:0]];
        [xmlString writeToFile:docDir atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
        [serializedData writeToFile:docDir atomically:YES];
```

However, after I send the email and try to open the xls file, the xml is displayed in the spreadsheet instead. Could anyone please lead me to the right direction to create this xls file?

Comment: hmm, works for me with Excel 2010

Comment: thanks for your comment! yes it did work on Excel 2010. however it shows an error that the file format doesn't match the file extension. and it doesn't open in google docs and iwork. so i think the problem might be from the xml document that i'm saving.

Comment: does anyone maybe know a good way to form an XML document which could be supported by Google Spreadsheets and Numbers as well?

Comment: you could create a Google Table Docs document and export the doc als xlsx

Comment: The xls file extension is not the XML variant, use xlsx.

Comment: did you solve this problem? let us know please

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same thing as the OP, and gave up. I eventually used libxls to open and read xls files, and wrote the files out using csv. (libxls can't write xls, just read it).

http://libxls.sourceforge.net

I haven't tried it, but xlslib claims to write excel files. It has an update in Jan 6 2014 saying it can work in iOS:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xlslib/files/

Also, read why it's so hard to write excel files, because it's true and funny:
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/02/19.html

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in the following special tag at the top of the document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
[...]
```

I just tried this tag with your XML and it worked on my Windows7 machine - I saved your document as 'test.excel.xml' - and the `<?mso...>` tag was enough for Windows to recognize the format as Excel.

There is an example here as well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats

Comment: With the file extension .xml this works with Excel 2010 on Windows7. With Excel 2011 on Mac OSX you have to use the file extension .xls for the same file content. I don't know of a variant that would work on both platforms, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

## This is the code for create XLS file

```
 NSMutableString *stringToWrite = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
 [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"First Name /t Last Name /t Full Name /tPhone Number /tEmail /t Job/t organizationName /tNote\n\n"]];
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
      for(int i = 0 ;i<[Contact count];i++)     {
           [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/t",[[Contact objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"firstName"] ]];
           [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/t",[[Contact objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"lastName"] ]];
           [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/t",[[Contact valueForKey:@"userName"] objectAtIndex:i]]];
           [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/t",[[Contact objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"phoneNumber"] ]];
           [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/t",[[Contact objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"emailAddress"] ]];
           [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/t",[[Contact objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"jobTitle"] ]];
           [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/t",[[Contact  objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"organizationName"] ]];
           [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n",[[Contact objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"note"] ]];
      }
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
           NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
           NSString *documentDirectory=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
           NSString *strBackupFileLocation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentDirectory,@"ContactList.xls"];
           [stringToWrite writeToFile:strBackupFileLocation atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
      });
 });
```

Comment: how about for swift ?

Answer (score -4):

Try To create a CSV file format,it will be best method